# How i can use DOS Command in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, dos, windows-forms-designer

I want to run this "rar a -rr10 -s c:\backup.rar c:\file.txt" DOS command in vb.net, my main problem is that i want to compress file in Winrar software using vb.net coding. a button is press in window form that compress the file.

This "rar a -rr10 -s c:\backup.rar c:\file.txt" DOS command compress the file.txt to backup.rar

Tell me multiple ways if anyone know to complete above task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. Using [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) directly:**

```
Imports System.Diagnostics
...

Process.Start("rar.exe", "a -rr10 -s c:\backup.rar c:\file.txt")
```

**2. Using [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):**

```
Imports System.Diagnostics
...

Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("rar.exe")
startInfo.Arguments = "a -rr10 -s c:\backup.rar c:\file.txt"
' ... possibly set other parameters here... '

Process.Start(startInfo)
```

(Of course you might have to specify the path to `rar.exe` if it's not in the current directory.)

Comment: Thank you. but we must give the full path of rar.exe otherwise it will not worked.